# How to webpack mix Vue apps conditionally in laravel blade file

Tags: laravel-5, webpack, vuejs2

I want to compile only selected file based on usertype.  I've different vue instance file in resource/js and  I want to mix only one of them.Currently I'm doing this

```
@if(Auth::user())
<script defer src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"> 
@else
<script defer src="{{ mix('js/guestApp.js') }}"> 
@endif
```

But it takes path from public folder,instead of resources.  How do I achieve it?  Can I mix resources/js/app.js file from blade?

Comment: No you can't call any `resource` file from a Blade file because the client has only access to your `public` folder

Comment: How do I conditionally dynamic import router and store in my vue app.js. Is it correct way to make combination of SPA and MPA.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution and it is to conditionally using of js file

```
@if(Auth::user())
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
@else
<script src="{{ asset('js/guestApp.js') }}" defer></script>
@endif
```

And then using different Vue app for different user type-
"resources/js/Guest/app.js"

And in my webpack compiling all at once-

```
mix.js('resources/js/Guest/app.js', 'public/js/guestApp.js')
.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: I still dont understand why the whole vue app with all the unrequired templates downloads to user.Even if multipage application.And in my case it downloads on every route.